# Performance tuning this query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following (simple) query that it is taking about 22s to finish:

```
SELECT 
    c.city_name, c.task_name, COUNT(c.customer_id) AS customers, 
    ROUND(SUM(c.opportunitySize),2) AS opportunitySize
FROM
    customeropp AS c
WHERE 
    account_id = '1000' AND campaign_cycle = 'm07a2020'
GROUP BY 
    c.city_name, c.task_name    
ORDER BY 
    opportunitySize DESC        
FOR JSON PATH
```

My understanding is that indexing can improve the speed so I have also added the following indexes

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_campaign_and_account 
    ON customeropp (campaign_cycle, account_id) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_city_name 
    ON customeropp (city_name) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_task_name 
    ON customeropp (task_name)  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_opportunitySize 
    ON customeropp (opportunitySize DESC)  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

There are some other indexes but are not relevant to this particular query.

The columns types are as follows:

[image]

The table used is about 3 million records right now and the db runs in a serverless Azure Database plan (up to 40 vCores, up to 120 GB memory).

Any idea on how I can make this run faster?

**EDIT:**

Execution plan available at: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkSt_mQKv

Comment: Can you please post an *actual* execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: What's the execution plan? The query is *not* simple - converting results to JSON is expensive. Ordering by an *aggregate* requires calculating and spooling all results in tempdb before ordering th, whicemh means none of the indexes can be used to accelerate the sort operation

Comment: Getting the _actual execution plan_ is explained [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/). You could try a [covering index](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) on `( account_id, campaign_cycle, city_name, task_name ) include ( customer_id, opportunitySize )`. It handles both the `where` and `group by` clauses, in that order, and provides the remaining data needed for the `select` and `order by` clauses.

Comment: @HABO wow... with you covering index suggestion the query is now under 1sec. that felt like magic!

Answer (score 0):

Use include column in index definition

```
CREATE  INDEX index_name
ON table_name(campaign_cycle, account_id)
INCLUDE(city_name, task_name, opportunitySize,  customer_id );
```

Comment: This one seems to improve query performance but not as much as @HABO suggestion above

Comment: It is better selected columns were in included columns

Comment: @Mrsmiri The index primarily improves performance of the `where` clause ( `account_id` and `campaign_cycle`), but it can also improve the performance of `group by ( `city_name` and `task_name` ) by sorting those columns. At that point the only `select` columns that aren't already in the index are `customer_id` and `opportunitySize`. They could be retrieved from the table rows, but using `include` to add them to the index allows the query to be executed without accessing the table rows at all. In theory, at least. Perhaps @JavierC would add the new execution plan to the post so we can see.

Comment: @HABO here's the new execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byhv6IEFD